# Jquery jscrollpane horizontal scroll direction scroll right

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, horizontal-scrolling

How i can adjust the jquery jscrollpane horizontal scroll with scroll drag right to left instead of the standard display? 
I have adjusted the css with `direction:rtt and float:right`, but the jscroll drag not worked properly. How i can adjust the `css/js` of the `jscrollpane horizontal scroll` to right display, i used the jquery.jscrollpane.min.js plugin ? how i can adjust the `.jspContainer`, something like `Scrollbar on right`.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call [scrollToX](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html#scrollToX) directly after initialising the scrollpane then it should scroll directly to the right hand side and the user will be able to scroll backwards.

Something like:

```
$(function()
{
    var pane = $('.scroll-pane');
    pane.jScrollPane(
        {
            // Any settings you need
        }
    );
    var api = pane.data('jsp');
    api.scrollToX(9999, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's work properly instead of changing the css and scroll direction.